# Error: [Errno 71] Protocol error: pyvenv

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, vagrant, centos7

I am using Centos7 with vagrant and virtualbox on windows10.
I am trying to create pyvenv virtual environment to develop python web apps with django. I have installed python 3.4.

However, when I type 
`pyvenv-3.4 name_of_environment`,
it gives back an error `Error: [Errno 71] Protocol error: 'lib' -> '/vagrant/django_apps/app1/name_of_environment/lib64'`

What is wrong?

Comment: Are you activating the virtualenv?

Answer (score 0):

`pyvenv-3.4 --without-pip name_of_environment`
worked

looks like pip was not installed.

thanks for the help.