# Why the 'Protocol Error' is raised when i try to build virtual enviroment with pyvenv?

Tags: python, vagrant, virtualenv, pyvenv

My host machine is win8 and virtual machine is Ubuntu 16. I make a dir--web_django in the Ubuntu as the synced folder. When I try to use `pyvenv` create a virtual environment, the error is raised:

```
Error: [Errno 71] Protocol error: 'lib' -> '/home/ubuntu/web_django/web/lib64'
```

So, why the error is raised?

I guess that the reason is i set the dir, web_django, to be the synced folder in `vagrant file`. But i use `virtualwrapper` successfully in the `web_django`.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40086091/error-errno-71-protocol-error-pyvenv/40120623

Comment: I tried `--without-pip`, not work.